# left side bar in twiki

Tags: twiki

i want to do things as below in twiki:

1. a list of hyperlink in left sidebar
2. when I click hyperlink in sidebar, the content is rendered in right side.

Actually i want to organize my documents as google code wiki.

Could you help me how to do that in twiki?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **edit the topic WebLeftBar** to contain the list of hyperlinks.

WebLeftBar works per web, so you have to edit the WebLeftBar topic of every web you want to impact. 
For example. to tweak the Main-Web, you edit http://example.com/bin/view/Main/WebLeftBar (replace example.com with your domain). If you want your left bar to be the same across all webs, you might consider to include one web's WebLeftBar into all the other WebLeftBar topics so that you have to edit only one topic if you want to change your left bar.

**Note:** I do not work with twiki but with [foswiki](http://foswiki.org), which is a twiki fork. That means, some details might be different in your installation, but I'm pretty confident that the mechanism works for twiki as well.